# parallel transportation on submanifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

$M$ is a Riemannian manifold, $N$ is a submanifold of $M$, not totally geodesic. Given two points $p,q \in N$, let $\gamma_N$, $\gamma_M$ be the geodesics connecting $p$, $q$ in $N$ and $M$, respectively.
Let $\xi \in {T_p}N$, $\xi $ orthogonal to ${{\dot \gamma }_N}(p)$. Is $\xi $ orthogonal to ${{\dot \gamma }_M}(p)$?  Does the result of parallel transportation of $\xi$ from $p$ to $q$ in $N$ coincide with that in $M$? If not, please give counter-examples.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not, to both questions.  I think two general points on a helix in a right circular cylinder ($N$) in $M=\Bbb R^3$ should work for both.

Comment: Or a circle in the plane...

Comment: @RyanBudney: I was going to swear at you :), but then the only $\xi$ available is $0$.

Comment: It seems to be true for a sphere to me... I think you need a less symmetric counterexample.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: I don't believe you, but perhaps I'm being a dope. Please enlighten.

Comment: $\gamma_M$ is a straight line and $\gamma_N$ is an arc of a great circle, and they lie in a common plane spanned by ${\dot \gamma}$ (either of them) and the normal to the sphere. Since $\xi$ is orthogonal to $\dot \gamma_N$ and to the normal, it is orthogonal to this plane, and thus to $\dot \gamma_M$. Since $\xi$ is orthogonal to the great circle it's unchanged (as a vector in $T_pM$) by parallel transport along $\gamma_N$. This is just intuition but I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: Parallel transport is definitely different. In $\mathbb R^3$ the vector doesn't change. It sure does in the sphere. You're right about orthogonality, however.

Comment: In spherical polar coordinates the metric is $\sin^2 \phi d\theta^2 + d\phi^2$. WLOG let $p,q$ be on the equator $\phi = \pi/2$. $\xi$ is then a multiple of $\partial_\phi$, with relevant Christoffel symbol $\nabla_\theta \partial_\phi = \cot(\phi) \partial_\theta = 0$. Thus the constant vector $\partial_\phi=\partial_z$ is parallel along the equator.

Comment: Oh, ugh, you're right, of course. I'm sick and not thinking well.